# how to forbid to screen reader read options length in select

Tags: select, combobox, accessibility, screen-readers

CromeVox screen reader reads wrong options length for select.
Technically right, but not what I need.

```html
<select name="month" id="month">
  <option value="" disabled selected style="display: none;">Month</option>
  <option value="01">January</option>
  <option value="02">February</option>
  <option value="03">March</option>
  <option value="04">April</option>
  <option value="05">May</option>
  <option value="06">June</option>
  <option value="07">July</option>
  <option value="08">August</option>
  <option value="09">September</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

It reads "combobox two of thirteen"
How to tell screen reader to not read list length at all or force it read "combobox two of twelve"?

https://jsfiddle.net/mrs_kva/5wk6xjt9/

I cant remove empty option.

UPD:
on w3.org presented example have this issue too
[see here](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/combobox/combobox-select-only.html#ex1-codepenbutton).
Despite there are 12 fruits in select reader says "13"

Comment: Oh I see now, you are applying a hack to force users to not choose the empty option, but to still show it as the current value in the initial state. Applying `display: none` should remove the options from the accessibility tree, which works well in Firefox. It reports 12 options. If there’s an example on the ARIA Authoring Practices Guide, it is not very likely that has accessibility issues. Notice, though, that they do not apply the display-none-hack. My recommendation would hence be to remove the `display: none`, I guess you have validation for the empty value any way.

Comment: You might try adding `aria-hidden` additionally to `display: none`. Also, you could add [the `hidden` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) instead of using `style`, which is shorter, but won’t change what ChromeVox does.

Comment: You may use aria-posinset and aria-setsize, but it's probably overkill. In any case, the best is to not use hack to hide the default option, and make the appropriate error handling before submit and on the server.

Comment: The hack is also trying to mimic a label for the select.  You shouldn't put the select's label as a value of the select itself.  You should have a separate element for the label.

Comment: Thanks! aria-posinset + aria-setsize, aria-hidden, aria-disabled, dropping select role to "none" or  "presentation", set role "option" only for needed option doesnt works.